# When accessing page get Error 404[after deploying website to app engine]

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, http-status-code-404

I made website using java.
which work correclty on local host.

but when I deploy it on google app engine.
It give me 404 Error.

- Problem link: http://webenggproject.appspot.com/signin.jsp
- localhost/signin.jsp [ work correclty on localhost ]

  `<div class="offset4">`
        `<a href="signin.jsp" class="btn  btn-large btn-primary span2">login</a>`

              `<a href="signup.jsp" class="btn btn-large span2">signup</a>    </div>`

Comment: You should post more code. Do you still get a 404? The link is working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Servlet to access your jsp...

Config web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Signin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.SigninServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Signin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/signin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet :

```
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SigninServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.sendRedirect("signin.jsp");
    }
}
```

dont forget to change your link :

```
<a href="signin" class="btn btn-large btn-primary span2">login</a>
```

Comment: welcome. You can also use same servlet for signup by add some variable such as `signin?action=signup` then you need to add some logic in your servlet.

Comment: I have created a complete website on my development machine using Netbeans as IDE and Mysql as database. Problem only occurs when I start deploying it to google appengine.

Comment: **Again got Error 404**. I check on my friends laptop there it worked.

Comment: what link you use to request?

Comment: http://webenggproject.appspot.com/signin.jsp : Now its again working **Strange**. Thanks for your time Daniel, I think google is playing pranks with me.:)